# Error downloading file: Error: Unexpected content type: text/html at Proxy.downloadFile

Tags: vue.js, download, xlsx, vue-composition-api, codeigniter-4

Here is my Vuejs code with composition API

```js
const downloadFile = async filePath => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/downloadPDS/${filePath}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
      },
      responseType: 'blob'
    })

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorMessage = await response.text()
      throw new Error(
        `HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}. Message: ${errorMessage}`
      )
    }
    const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if (contentType !== 'application/octet-stream') {
      throw new Error(`Unexpected content type: ${contentType}`)
    }
    const content = await response.blob()

    console.log('Response Headers:', response.headers)
    console.log('Response Content:', content)

    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(content)
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = url
    link.download = extractFileName(filePath)
    document.body.appendChild(link)
    link.click()
    document.body.removeChild(link)
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error downloading file:', error)
    toastr.error('Error downloading file')
  }
}
```

I have this in my codeigniter 4 function for download

```php
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filePath) . '"');
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($filePath));
ob_clean();
readfile($filePath);
exit();
```

It shows this error when clicking the download Error downloading file:

> Error:
> Unexpected content    type: text/html
> at Proxy.downloadFile

P.S. im downloading a xlsx file tge pds ($userPds['pds']) in phpmyadmin is text type it hold the     path of the file also in postman when i try to download it works well and no error but in vue it has error i also try to remove this

```
if (contentType !== 'application/octet-stream') {
  throw new Error(`Unexpected content type: ${contentType}`)
}
```

it downloadS the xlsx but it has this error when opening the file it show

> file format or file extenxion is not valid. verify that the
> file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the
> format of the file

> this is the sample path that pds hold its save in Codeigniter 4 public folder pds/User_First_User_Last/pds_User_First_User_Last1706191858.xlsx

Comment: it works in me now i use this instead 
<a :href="`http://localhost:8080/api/downloadPDS/${pds.id}`">test</a>